# Save new data to another realm database and replace current

Tags: android, realm

## Current situation

In my application I'm saving into default `realm database` more or less 100Mb of data using the `insert` method with a `JsonReader` instantiated from a downloaded `json file`.

Now: everything works fine, but saving that amount of data takes some minutes (between 2 and 5) just for the parse-save operation. (I use `OKHTTP` to download a json file -`.txt`- and `InputStream` -> `JsonReader` -> `Gson` -> `realm.insert` for the parsing-inserting operation)

## Possible improvement idea

Since in my app logics this operation might also be done on a background thread, I was wandering if it was possible to perform an operation like the following:

1. asynchronously download data from internet
2. saving data into a `new realm database`
3. once done, prompt the user to update data
4. take some tables from the new database and put them into the old one with a bulk delete-insert (I don't care of losing old datas for those tables, new ones are always the correct ones and the user can't edit them).

## Possible problems with that implementation

I'm fine with the development of this solution, but before performing a refactor operation like that, I have a couple of questions:

1. Can I perform the save operation to `database2` in a `background thread` and let the users work with `UI` and `database1` on `main thread` or both dbs will be locked during `database2 insert` operation?
2. If my current db uses `default configurations`, can I create another realm db with `custom configurations` just passing a different db name?

This is what I would like to do for the final replace operation (obv it's just a sample, just take the concept out of this):

```
Realm oldRealm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
Realm newRealm = Realm.getInstance(secondConfig);

//assume it's inside a transaction
oldRealm.delete(mytable.class);
oldRealm.insert(newRealm.where(myTable.class).findAll());
```

About this:

- Is this a plausible solution?
- Will this solution be faster than downloading and inserting using JsonReader?
- Is there a better way for that?

Thanks all and sorry for the long post/bad english

## Edit

**My download-save code** (semplified. I download +- 30 files synchronously and I save them into my database. The biggest one is around 70Mb and it takes really a lot for the write transaction):

I removed not useful code and left only the relevant part. The line taking all the time is the insert into the database.
I also tried not using Gson but I need it since

```
//i'm inside an AsyncTask here
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
    Realm realm = null;
    try {
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

        String url = myDownloadFileURL;

        //here I download my files with OkHttp
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(600, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(600, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .retryOnConnectionFailure(true)
                .build();

        Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url)
                .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .addHeader("Connection", "close")
                .build();
        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

        ResponseBody responseBody = response.body();

        if (responseBody == null) {
            return null;
        }

        // I save all my files into the internal storage because otherwise they will make the connection timeout
        File extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File myFolder = new File(extStorageDirectory, BuildConfig.FLAVOR);
        myFolder.mkdirs();
        final File file = new File(myFolder, fileName + ".txt");
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        InputStream is = responseBody.byteStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096]; //Buffer size, Usually 1024-4096
        int len;
        while ((len = is.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) > 0) {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();

        responseBody.close();
        client.connectionPool().evictAll();

        //here I analyze my downloaded data and I save them to realm.
        //I put only one case, they are all the same :)
        switch (fileName) {
            case "Cities": {
                realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                    @Override
                    public void execute(Realm realm) {
                        try {
                           // {0} --> REFER BELOW
                        } catch (Exception error) {
                            //removed not useful code
                        }
                    }
                });
                break;
            }
            default:
                break;
        }
        response.close();

    } catch (IOException error) {
        //removed not useful code
    } finally {
        if (realm != null) {
            realm.close();
        }
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {
    //removed not useful code
}
```

{0} --> REFER BELOW

For that part of code (the slow one) I tried many ways.. those 2 are the best ones for performance and non-error thrown:

1) Using a parsed list

```
Log.wtf("SYNC", "City - start delete");
realm.delete(City.class);
Log.wtf("SYNC", "City - end delete, start create");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
realm.insert((List<City>) gson.fromJson(reader, new TypeToken<List<City>>(){}.getType()));
Log.wtf("SYNC", "City - end create");
```

2) using JsonReader

```
Log.wtf("SYNC", "City - start delete");
realm.delete(Meter.class);
Log.wtf("SYNC", "City - end delete, start create");
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
JsonReader jReader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
jReader.beginArray();
while (jReader.hasNext()) {
    realm.insert((City) gson.fromJson(jReader, City.class));
}
jReader.endArray();
jReader.close();
Log.wtf("SYNC", "City - end create");
```

In both cases the insert operation is pretty long.

The problem might be Gson, but I need to parse my models because I have some Date fields that have to be parsed with a custom typeAdapter.

Comment: It'll crash saying "you need to be in a write transaction", because `executeTransaction` is missing.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce yeah I know that, it was just a line written to explain what I was thinking :)  My goal was to know if the process might work or not and if that might be worth the effort

Comment: I'm actually more curious why it takes 2-5 minutes to build initially. Is it done in a single transaction? What does method profiling say?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I added the relevant code of my download AsyncTask. It is surely optimizable, but I don't really know how